# Android studio do not update changes to layout design?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

I have notice that Android Studio doesnt update changes made to layout and it always displays old layout design. so i went to check layout folder in explorer and notice that it has three different layout folder namimg : layout , layout-v17 and layout-v20. I have notice that both layout-v17 and 20 contains old layout and was never updated with new layout design. so i have deleted those two folder and it started working .   Is it a good idea to delete them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't create spcial versions of your layouts for particular api versions, it is ok that you deleted the folders.

That kind of folders are used to keep resources for specific api versions. E.g. you can have an activity_main.xml layout in layout folder and in layout-v17 folder. Then, the layout from the default folder would be used for devices with api level < 17 and the layout from layout-v17 for sevices with api level 17 and higher.